# Can i add a seccond Web Application to my local sharepoint installation?

Tags: web-application

When i go to Central Administration - Application Management on my local sharepoint installating, i can only view the current web applications. I cannot add a new or delete an existing web application. I'm logged in as a farm admin.

Did i forget something?

EDIT: I just saw that when i go to central administration, i see an alert that my securtity token service is not running. I guess this has something to do with my problem.

Comment: Dont you see the new button at the top left in the ribbon?

Comment: i can see it, but it's disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Central Administration, select "Manage web applications". In the "Web Applications" tab of the ribbon you should see a "New" button. If you don't see the new button, you don't have applicable permissions to create a web application.

Comment: I can manage users, when i go to user groups, i see my own user in the farm administrators group. What's wrong here?

Comment: Try logging as as the installation account; this should validate that it's an issue with your permissions and not the farm itself.

Comment: I'm logged in with the installation account. (= My current windows user) I've still this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you start Internet Explorer with elevated privilegies. The New button will be disabled otherwise.

Comment: I start as administrator.